# VBA Excel Loop - novice user

Tags: vba, excel

I am a novice at VBA but I am hoping an expert can help me with what I am trying to do.

Essentially using Record Macro and my basic grasp of VBA I have created the below; what I am trying to do is change the B4,D4 to B5,D5 B6,D6 etc... for 100 loops.

I am completely stuck and was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction.

Many many thanks.

Dar

```
If Sheets("BUILDING").Range("B4").Value = "" Then

Else

Sheets("CALCULATOR").Select

Range("B1").ClearContents

Sheets("BUILDING").Select

Range("D4").Select

Selection.Copy

Sheets("CALCULATOR").Select

Range("B1").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Application.Run "Test1"

End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The recorder is a great tool to learn how to write specific things in vba.  It is bad in that it uses `Select` and `Activate` which are slow.
2. When only values are wanted just assign the value directly.
3. You loop with `For`, `For Each`, `Do`, ... there are others google can teach you.

---

```
Dim i as Long
for i = 4 to 104
    IF worksheets("CALCULATOR").Cells(i,"B").Value = "" then _
        worksheets("CALCULATOR").Cells(i,"B").Value = Worksheets("BUILDING").cells(i,"D").value
Next i
```

Comment: In the recorder's defense, it uses `Select` and `Activate` specifically because it's *recording* user actions, because that's its very nature =)

Comment: Scott, Many thanks for helping me. I have copied and pasted exactly what you have put (replacing my If to End If statement above) and when I run it I get  Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: On which line?  @Dar

Comment: @Dar make sure the sheet names are spelled correctly, I may have a typo there.

Comment: Sorry to bother but is there a way to make "for i = 4 to the last row with data in (BUILDING) column D"?

Comment: That is a new question but before you ask check out this question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba .  Try using that to find the last row and if you get stuck come back and ask a new question. @Dar

Answer (score 0):

To build on Scott's answer, you could set a "range object" to a cell in your target worksheet, and offset the position of the pasted cell one click each time you loop.  That gives you a little more flexibility:

```
dim i as long, r as range

set r = worksheets("CALCULATOR").range("B1")

for i = 0 to 99
    if worksheets("BUILDING").cells(i + 4, "B") <> "" then
        r.offset(i, 0) = worksheets("BUILDING").cells(i + 4, "D")
    end if

next i
```